# Amazon S3 JS SDK putBucketLifecycleConfiguration giving XML Schema Error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using the AWS javascript SDK on node. I'm trying to set my bucket life cycle configuration but somewhere my structure is not correct and I can't see where.

I'm basing my code on : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketLifecycleConfiguration-property

Version : aws-sdk@2.4.9

When I execute the code I get :

> The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against
>   our published schema

Any idea what is wrong with it?

```
let parms = {
        Bucket: 'mybucketname',
        LifecycleConfiguration: {
            Rules: [
                {
                    Prefix: 'uploads', /* required */
                    Status: 'Enabled', /* required */
                    AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload: {
                        DaysAfterInitiation: 0
                    },
                    Expiration: {
                        Date: Date.UTC(1970, 1),
                        Days: 1,
                        ExpiredObjectDeleteMarker: true
                    },
                    ID: '1',
                    NoncurrentVersionExpiration: {
                        NoncurrentDays: 0
                    },
                    NoncurrentVersionTransitions: [
                        {
                            NoncurrentDays: 0,
                            StorageClass: 'STANDARD_IA'
                        },
                        /* more items */
                    ],
                    Transitions: [
                        {
                            Date: Date.UTC(1970, 1),
                            Days: 0,
                            StorageClass: 'STANDARD_IA'
                        },
                        /* more items */
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    };        
return this.s3.putBucketLifecycleConfiguration(parms).promise();
```

Comment: What is the version of your SDK

Comment: Ahh yes. aws-sdk@2.4.7

Comment: I see there is a 2.4.9 going to try that. Geez got 2.4.7 only two weeks ago. :)

Comment: No go version 2.4.9 also giving the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working for anyone interested: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1071